# Key binding to go up by one directory (in Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

In Zsh, I have a key binding to go up by one directory (very useful):

```
# C-M-u: up-directory
up-directory() {
    builtin cd .. && zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N up-directory
bindkey '\e\C-u' up-directory
```

It's very nice. So nice that I would like to get it as well in my Bash config.

How can we do that?

**PS-** Transferred from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076286/key-binding-to-go-up-by-one-directory-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that. 
It's not as elegant or straight forward as with zsh but it's doable in bash using `bind`.
You can not only bind built in Readline functions (listed with `bind -l`) but other macros and shell functions too.

`bind -m emacs -x '"\C-u":"cd .."'` will bind a shell command (`cd ..`) to the keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>) in emacs mode (the default mode).

Note that your prompt will probably not reflect the change. 
If you leave out `-x` the string will instead be typed out for you so `"cd ..\n"` achieves the same result.

Comment: The cd works, when this is bound to a free key binding. However, as the prompt is not refreshed, that's not really usable...

Comment: I prefer this intermediate solution, which is not a hack: `bind '"\e\C-u": "cd ..\n"'`